# Critical Path - dask

Tags: python, dask

In the Dask Distributed project, there is a mention regarding critical path for scheduling. I am a little bit confused regarding what this entails. How Dask decides what is a critical path? It is only based on the number of nodes.

Comment: You mean here: https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling-policies.html?highlight=critical%20path#choosing-tasks ?

Comment: yes! exactly. I have seen that link but it is not clear how they defined a critical path